Robust two-column HTML layout for emails that works in Outlook.exe, howto without tables?
Currently, we use tables in our email software to create a two-column layout like below, displaying avatars of the discussion participants to the left of the actual e-mail text, similar to a forum discussion:

What would be a simple and robust HTML approach to achieving a similar two-column layout, without using tables?
The main problem is that this has to function in Outlook.exe as well.
All solutions similar to the ones below don't work in Outlook. Outlook disregards all horizontal positioning, and simply positions the text below the avatar image and aligned left, instead of in a separate vertical column to the right of the image.
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="float: left; width: 100px;">
    <!-- Avatar -->
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/90" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 111px;">
    <!-- E-Mail text content -->
    <p>Here is the remaining content of the email, which is 
    displayed to the right of the avatar, in a virtual 
    column so to speak. This text can be formatted 
    and filled with further content, such as 
    additional paragraphs, lists, images, etc.</p>
  </div>
</div>

Here is a JSFiddle. Note that as mentioned, this doesn't work in Outlook.
The below variant also doesn't work in Outlook. Outlook simply disregards the div positioning completely.
<div style="width: 100%; columns: 2; column-gap: 20px;">
  <div style="width: 100px; break-inside: avoid;">
    <!-- Avatar -->
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/90" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- E-Mail text content -->
    <p>Here is the remaining content of the email, which is 
    displayed to the right of the avatar, in a virtual 
    column so to speak. This text can be formatted 
    and filled with further content, such as 
    additional paragraphs, lists, images, etc.</p>
  </div>
</div>


I don't know if this can help but you can try for the wrapper div {columns:2;}

Thanks, I've tried something along these lines (and added it to the question), but Outlook ignored the columns attribute as well.

Doesn't seem possible unless using display:table-row doesn't violate your requirement.

Perhaps this and this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12) will be of use to you.

Folks. Why is it that neither the natural intelligences gathered here nor various consulted artificial intelligences come up with the thought that the avatar and the 1 or 2 lines to the right of it can be arranged using "align=left", and everything below it simply indented a bit?
<img src="https://picsum.photos/55" alt="Avatar" style="width:55px; vertical-align:top;" align="left">
<p>Just the one, two lines of text to the right of the avatar image<br>
   Just the one, two lines of text to the right of the avatar image<br>
   Another line, possibly
</p>
<div style="margin-left: 55px;">
   <!-- E-Mail text content -->
   <p>Here is the remaining content of the email, which is 
      displayed to the right of the avatar, in a virtual 
      column so to speak. This text can be formatted 
      and filled with further content, such as 
      additional paragraphs, lists, images, etc.
   </p>
</div>

